# Where can I stop the timer is the best?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to ask a question about VB.Net.

I reads data from comport and filter the array to remove the dupplicate value and the Com Port send array like this ->

```
    1. Starting the machine first time. Will send 3 values. Many times happen for a day
    2. Second time and up will send 4 values.
```

The reason, I don't know when the starting round will come. No signal can present the first time.

```
Issue:
     1. If I give condition array.Count>=3
              + Never get the array fouth.

     2.  If I give condition array.Count=4
              + Never get first round.
     3. Machien will send data to Com port when Human press start the machine. The machine running 6 seconds.
```

The array 1,2,3 and 4 will send to display on screen as needed.

Something need to do after got the exactly value. 1,2,3 and 4

1. Clear the array; 2. stop timer. But if array not full 4 values, then the array can't be clearedand can't stop the timer. Maybe I lack of some experience here.

#My coding:

```
        '1.
        Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TimerLS9000.Tick
            
            collectrawdata(SerialPort1)
            Call ShowData()
            
        End Sub

        '2.
        Public Sub collectrawdata(ByVal commport As SerialPort)
            Try
                Dim mySTR As String

                If (Not commport.IsOpen) Then
                    commport.Open()
                End If
                
                '''
                ''''
                
                mySTR = String.Empty
                mySTR = commport.ReadExisting

                If commport.IsOpen Then
                    commport.Close()
                End If

                ArrRAW.Add(mySTR.ToString()) ''Value like 33.0938 & vbCrLf

            Catch ex As Exception
                throw new Exception '''
            End Try

         End Sub
            
         '3.
         Private Sub ShowData()
                Try
                    If ArrRAW.Count > 0 Then

                        ''''Remove dupplicate value
                        For j As Int32 = 0 To ArrRAW.Count - 1
                            valueX = ArrRAW(j)

                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueX) Then
                                Continue For
                            End If

                            If Not IsNumeric(valueX) And CType(valueX, Double) < 0 Then
                                Continue For
                            End If

                            If CType(valueX, Double) < 35.00 OrElse CType(valueX, Double) > 55.00 Then
                                Continue For
                            End If

                            If Not ArrREAL.Contains(valueX) Then
                                ArrREAL.Add(valueX)
                            End If
                        Next


                        'get lastest values ==>> My question will focus here.
                        
                        ''''If ArrRAW.Count>=3 Then '''Only completed for first round.
                            ''''Value1 = ArrREAL(1) ''Ignore value at index 0 when arr = 3
                            '''Value2 = ArrREAL(2)
                            
                        ''==>>One question here. How to separate arr = 3 or 4? -> when reset or first time using the machine is always =3 but no signal can present this situation.
                        
                        If ArrREAL.Count = 4 Then '''First round will never complete
                        
                            Value1 = ArrREAL(2) ''Ignore value at index 1 & 0 when arr = 4
                            Value2 = ArrREAL(3)

                            'Assign to UI
                            label1.Text = Value1.ToString()
                            label2.Text = Value2.ToString()

                            Timer1.Enabled = False

                            Call SaveDB(Value1,Value2)

                            ArrRAW.Clear()
                            ArrREAL.Clear()

                        End If

                    End If

                Catch ex As Exception
                    Return
                End Try

            End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If  you only get 3 values on the first time only, then declare a [Boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/boolean-data-type) to track whether this is the first batch or a subsequent batch...

Comment: How to detect it is the first batch?
Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you only get 3 values on the first time only, then declare a
> Boolean to track whether this is the first batch or a subsequent
> batch... – Idle_Mind
>
> How to detect it is the first batch? Can you give an example? – Harina
> Ada

I was thinking maybe something like this?

```
Private FirstBatch As Boolean = True

Private Sub ShowData()

    ' ... other code ...

    If FirstBatch Then
        If ArrREAL.Count >= 3 Then
            FirstBatch = False

            ' ... process first batch ...

        End If
    Else
        If ArrREAL.Count = 4 Then

            ' ... process other batches here ...

        End If
    End If

    ' ... other code ...

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Idle_Mind
as of your comment, it is impossible to completed because every timer_Tick will run to this method and the first batch condition will be matched. The condition at 4 values will be never used.

Comment: And when the firstbatch=False, the machine is return to first batch again but the program doesn't reset <Still false> then can't step into the condition.

Comment: It's my first experience in using timer with serialport

Comment: I still think the approach will work; I just changed from `ArrRAW` to `ArrREAL`.

Answer (score 0):

Example of raw data.

```
        value 1 = 35.008
                  35.008
                  35.008
                  35.008
                  35.008
                  35.008
                  35.008
        value 2 = 40.01
                  40.01
                  40.01
                  40.01
                  40.01
                  40.01
                  40.01
                  40.01
        value 3 = 45.89
                  45.89
                  45.89
                  45.89
                  45.89
                  45.89
                  45.89
                  45.89
                  45.89
```

=> if not first batch

```
        value 4 = 20.05
                  20.05
                  20.05
                  20.05
                  20.05
                  20.05
                  20.05
```

one value is one timer tick or one timer tick will get only one value and repeat. That why I have to use "ArrREAL" to filter dupplicate value.